# Spring Boot - replace default embedded Tomcat connector

Tags: spring-boot

I need to add an AJP connector to embedded Tomcat and **disable (or replace) the default connector** that listens on 8080.

I've tried customizing this with EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer, but I can't get a handle on the Tomcat object to replace the default connector created there. As a result I end up with the http port on 8080 in addition to my AJP ports.

Next, I've tried extending [TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/tomcat/TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java) and overriding its getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer method. Per the JavaDoc, this appears to be the perfect place to replace the default connector, but it still ends up being enabled (and doesn't create my AJP connector either). Any ideas what I might be missing? I've verified with the debugger that my configuration is being run.

**Per answer below, here's the cleanest solution:**

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory myFactory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    myFactory.setProtocol("AJP/1.3");
    myFactory.setPort(9000);
    return myFactory;
}

@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer2() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
            tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
                @Override
                public void customize(Connector connector) {
                    connector.setRedirectPort(9001);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the "connector.setRedirectPort(9001)" ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `TomcatConnectorCustomizer` to configure the existing connector to use AJP by adding it to the `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` bean and reconfigure it to AJP:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {

    // AJP port defined in properties (default 666)
    @Value("${tomcat.ajp.port:666}")
    private Integer ajpPort;

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer ajpContainerCustomizer() {
        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
                TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
                tomcat.setProtocol("AJP/1.3");
                tomcat.setPort(ajpPort);
            }

        };
    }

}
```